# Dropping bibtex fields under certain conditions using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

One usually runs into page limit problems when preparing conference abstracts. I would like to drop certain fields but this should be dependent on other fields. I already know how to drop the series field. This is done in the MWE below. But I want to drop the address field when the publisher is Cambridge University Press or Oxford University Press. It would also be helpful to be able to drop certain fields depending on the bibtex type. number for articles, for example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{Ramchand2008,
address={Cambridge}, 
series={Cambridge Studies in Linguistics},
number= 116, 
title={Verb Meaning and the Lexicon: {A} {F}irst {P}hase {S}yntax}, 
publisher={Cambridge University Press}, 
author={Ramchand, Gillian Catriona}, 
chapter = {10},
year={2008}, 
collection={Cambridge Studies in Linguistics 116},
DOI={10.1017/CBO9780511486319}
}
\end{filecontents}



\usepackage[
        natbib=true,
        style=langsci-unified,
        url = false,
        doi = false,
        backend = biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\DeclareFieldInputHandler{chapter}{%
    \def\NewValue{}}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{series}{%
    \def\NewValue{}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic comment: it’s better practice to put braces around the whole word for case protection instead of just the first letter. So: `title={Verb Meaning and the Lexicon: {A} {First} {Phase} {Syntax}}`. Otherwise kerning might be off. See http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-capbibtex (“Braces can prevent kerning between letters, so it is in general preferable to enclose entire words and not just single letters in braces to protect them.”)

Comment: Ha, we do this everywhere. This was just copied from another database. Sorry for this. We do this also for searchability. But Sebastian keeps telling and showing me that there is no difference. Maybe it is font specific or engine specific. Thanks for the hin though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field deletion with `\DeclareFieldInputHandler` happens at a very early stage when the data is read by `biblatex` from the `.bbl` file (which is generated by Biber). The order in which fields are read is not guaranteed, so you cannot make informed decisions at that point whether or not a certain field is present. That means that `\DeclareFieldInputHandler` is not suitable to conditionally suppress fields.

So I would probably use Biber sourcemaps here. The advantage of sourcemaps is that they can access all entry data (as given in the `.bib` file) and they can even use regular expressions, which is very handy for the "... University Press" thing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=langsci-unified,
  url=false,
  doi=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=publisher, 
            match=\regexp{\A(Cambridge|Oxford)\s+University\s+Press\Z},
            final]
      \step[fieldset=location, null]
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=chapter, null]
      \step[fieldset=series, null]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Ramchand2008,
  address    = {Cambridge}, 
  series     = {Cambridge Studies in Linguistics},
  number     = 116, 
  title      = {Verb Meaning and the Lexicon: A First Phase Syntax}, 
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press}, 
  author     = {Ramchand, Gillian Catriona}, 
  chapter    = {10},
  year       = {2008}, 
  collection = {Cambridge Studies in Linguistics 116},
  DOI        = {10.1017/CBO9780511486319}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Ramchand, Gillian Catriona. 2008. Verb meaning and the lexicon: a first phase syntax. Cambridge University Press.]

Comment: Cool! Even with an or in the regular expression!